# Unable to locate package curl while building dockerfile in gitlab pipeline

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci-runner, ubuntu-20.04

while I try to build ubuntu image and install packages like curl, git, wget, unzip it shows error like unable to locate the listed packages in gitlab pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to update the repository stored in the ubuntu image:

```bash
apt-get update
```

Then install your packages:

```bash
apt-get install --yes curl git wget unzip
```

The `--yes` option is useful in ci because apt-get in this way automatically confirms all questions. Indeed answering on logs of GitLab CI is not possible.

Here is a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that I put today in a whole new repo:

```yaml
stages:
  - build

build-job:
    stage: build
    image: ubuntu:jammy-20220428  
    script:
      - |
          apt-get update
          apt-get install --yes curl git wget unzip
```

And it works. You can try changing the ubuntu version.

Comment: yes, I used the command which you provided here, but it shows error.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? The fact is that for me it works with the minimal example above. Copy my snippet and verify it works, maybe your runner config has problems.